# plot outputs from one function by varying an input cell

Tags: excel, graph, plot, excel-2007

I'm experimenting with a formula to get the surface area of wire i can fit inside a particular space, ie a phone battery. i have set up the dimensions of the battery and calculated the total surface area for any particular input (wire thickness cellref D6).

I have used a long series of calculations to include changes in the number of times the wire can be folded to fit in the space.

What i want to do is see the effect of changing the input (wire thickness) on the output (total surface area CELLREF j6)

i want to know if there is a way to have excel either create an output list of values for an input list, without having me to manually change the values (im thinking inputs from 0.01-10 in steps of 0.01), or ideally have excel cycle through the calculations and plot a chart of the outputs for the inputs.

i know that i can use goal seek to find particular values, but i'm really more interested in graphically seeing the plot for the different wire thicknesses. (as the wire gets bigger the circumference gets bigger, surface area is affected, but as the wire gets smaller you can fit more folds etc.)

this is NOT an optimization/one value seeking task, but a plotting of results one.

any help is appreciated!
cheers guys.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you calculate your output but if based on say a value (such as `0.01`) in A1 (and other parameters) and that value in your formula is referenced as `A1` then with you formula in say B1 (copied down to B1000) with `=A1+.01` in A2 copied down to A1000 then you should have all you need to plot your chart.

Comment: Hi pnuts, i'm calculating the surface area by